# Asterisk REST ARI snoop (cURL)

Tags: rest, asterisk, asteriskami

I try to:
curl -v -u j123:j321 -X POST "http://localhost:8088/ari/channels/1421226074.4874/snoop?spy=SIP/695"

In response to receiving:
"message": "Invalid direction specified for spy"

I try to:
SIP/695; SIP:695, SIP@695, localhost@695, channel, channelName
It's all not working.

Call comes into the queue from sip-416 to queue_1 and distribute to 694. I need to connect 695 for wiretapping channel 1421226074.4874.

I only need to listen and not to whisper.
Help me please)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you what the problem is:

> "message": "Invalid direction specified for spy"

The spy parameter is a direction for spying, not the channel to spy on [(see reference documentation here)](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Channels+REST+API#Asterisk13ChannelsRESTAPI-snoopChannelWithId). You've already specified the channel to snoop on in the URI path - you need to specify the direction of the media in the spy parameter.

As an aside, apparently the auto generated wiki isn't display enum values, which is unfortunate. We'll have to fix that.

For reference, here's the parameter in the Swagger JSON:

```
                            "name": "spy",
                        "description": "Direction of audio to spy on",
                        "paramType": "query",
                        "required": false,
                        "allowMultiple": false,
                        "dataType": "string",
                        "defaultValue": "none",
                        "allowableValues": {
                            "valueType": "LIST",
                            "values": [
                                "none",
                                "both",
                                "out",
                                "in"
                            ]
                        }
```